# Bash completion sometimes meshes up my terminal when the completion function reads a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, bash-completion

So I've been having a problem with some cli programs. Sometimes when I kill the running process with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it leaves the terminal in a weird state (e.g. echo is turned off). Now that is to be expected for many cases, as killing a process does not give it a chance to restore the terminal's state. But I've discovered that for many other cases, bash completion is the culprit. As an example, try the following:

1. Start a new bash session as follows: `bash --norc` to ensure that no completions are loaded.
2. Define a completion function: `_completion_test() { grep -q foo /dev/null; return 1; }`.
3. Define a completion that uses the above function: `complete -F _completion_test rlwrap`.
4. Type *exactly* the following: <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> (i.e. `rlwrap cat` followed by a <kbd>Tab</kbd> and then by an <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
5. Wait for a second and then kill the process with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
6. The echo of the terminal should have not been turned off. So if you type any character, it will not be echoed by the terminal.

What is really weird is that if I remove the seemingly harmless `grep -q foo /dev/null` from the completion function, everything works correctly. In fact, adding a `grep -q foo /dev/null` (or even something even simpler such as `cat /dev/null`) to any completion function that was installed in my system, causes the same issue. I have also reproduced the problem with programs that don't use `readline` and without <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (e.g. `find /var`<kbd>Tab</kbd>`| head`, with the above completion defined for `find`).

Why does this happen?

**Edit**: Just to clarify, the above is a contrived example. In reality, what I am trying to do, is more like this:

```
_completion_test() {
    if grep -q "$1" /some/file; then
        #do something
    else
        #do something else
    fi
}
```

For a more concrete example, try the following:

```
_completion_test() {
    if grep -q foo /dev/null; then
        COMPREPLY=(cats)
    else
        return 1
    fi
}
```

But the mere fact that I am calling `grep`, causes the problem. I don't see why I can't call `grep` in this case.

Comment: What version of bash is this?

Comment: I have tried it with 4.3.42, 4.3.46, 4.4 beta 2, but I also tried it with older versions.

Comment: Reproduced with 4.1.2 but it doesn't even require `grep`/`cat`. I got it to happen with `_c_t() { blah; }`.

Comment: What did you use for `blah`? Literally `blah`? I found that some commands cause the problem, some don't.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help].  It may be better suited to the [Unix and Linux](//unix.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Yes, literally `blah` (as in a command that doesn't exist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer to this is very simple; it's a [bug](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2016-08/msg00124.html):

> This happens when a programmable completion function calls an external command during the execution of a completion function.  Bash saves the tty state after every successful job completes, so it can restore it if a job is killed by a signal and leaves the terminal in an undesired state.  In this case, we need to suppress that if the job that completes is run during programmable completion, since the terminal settings at that time are as readline sets them for line editing. This fix will be in the release version of bash-4.4.

Answer (score -1):

You're just doing a wrong implementation of the completion function. See the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html#Programmable-Completion-Builtins)

> -F function
>
> The shell function function is executed in the current shell environment. When it is executed, $1 is the name of the command
> whose arguments are being completed, $2 is the word being completed,
> and $3 is the word preceding the word being completed, as described
> above (see Programmable Completion). When it finishes, the possible
> completions are retrieved from the value of the COMPREPLY array
> variable.

for example the following implemenation:

```
_completion_test() { COMPREPLY=($(cat /dev/null)); return 1; }
```

doesn't break the terminal.

Regarding your original question why your completion function breaks terminal, I've played a little with `strace` and I saw that there are `ioctl` calls with `-echo` argument. I assume that when you are terminating it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> the `ioctl` with `echo` argument just isn't being called in order to restore the original state. Typing `stty echo` will bring the `echo` back.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't really answer my question. The `cat /dev/null` was just an example. In my actual implementation, I was using `grep`. I've updated my question to make that clearer. I really don't want to capture the output of that command in `COMPREPLY`.